# Change the theme of existing opencart app by keeping database

Tags: database, themes, opencart

I have an old opencart theme now i want t change the theme into a new one ,it contains more than 10000 products. Is it possible to change the theme keeping the db same?

Comment: yes it is possible. But take a backup, especially of database, in case anything goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can easily switch the theme here:

[image]

Comment: can you please explain how to upload the new theme?

Comment: This may be different for every theme so you should consult the README or INSTALL instructions that came with the theme.